# Stop SAS execution

Tags: sas

Quick question

Is there a one-liner (or something rather short) method of cancelling the execution of further SAS statements from withing the windowing environement.

These are the [methods](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/063-31.pdf) I know of but they get tiresome, espeacially in huge programs with a lot of comments. 
   I tried the `ABORT` and `STOP` statements but they close the windowing enviroment yet all I want is to stop execution at a certain point and go on my merry way.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that comes up on SAS-L every so often.  The answer is that it depends on what you're doing, largely.

The `run cancel` method is probably best if you are hoping to stop execution because of an error.  At the top of your program you do:

```
%let cancel =; *or any macro variable name, but cancel is most logical;
```

Then in every run step you have:

```
data whatever;
... do stuff ...;
run &cancel;
```

And each time you have some potential error, you check the error condition and then if it hits,`%let cancel=cancel;` and you're good.

If you are using macros, you can exit a macro smoothly with `%abort` as long as you either use no options or only use `cancel`.  Depending on what you're doing, you might set up your code to run in a macro (or macros) and use this option (although with the disadvantage of losing some log clarity).

Finally, if you're just interesting in being able to run a subset of your code, I recommend writing the code in multiple SAS programs for the bits you might want to run separately, then using `%include` from a master program to group them all together along with any macro variables you might want set that are shared.  This is similar to how in EG you would construct many smaller programs and then group them using the process flow diagram.

Comment: FYI `proc sql` also has a similar option called `noexec`.  The full syntax being `proc sql noexec;  .... do stuff.... ; quit`.  The contents of the proc will not be executed.  You can use the same technique Joe describes above for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following

```
%abort cancel;
```

Comment: That worked for me. data _ null _;
if &sitrouv>0 then call execute(
 "proc sql noprint;
  ...sqlQuery...;
 "
 );
 else abort cancel;
run;

Answer (score 1):

i've been searching for this too - documentation is not good on this one.  Trial and error (sigh...).  This, amazingly, undocumented feature worked for me:

```
data _null_ ;
  ABORT CANCEL ;
run ;
```

Pretty simple!  Nothing after that executed, and yet the SAS application remained open.

Comment: Not sure I would call the ABORT statement undocumented.  The problem is that it will totally stop your SAS session. So if the original question is taken to mean how can I stop a block of code that I submitted using SAS Display Manager then running ABORT will close SAS including all of the windows you were using to edit your program!